# Problema com complemento firefox em site que não dá refresh/navega por Ajax/JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-extensão

Estou desenvolvendo minha primeira Webextension(Complemento Firefox) e está funcionando adequadamente.

Porém, **estou com problemas quando parte do site é navegado sem dar refresh. Ou seja, a extensão não funciona pois só trabalha quando faz o refresh ou termina a requisição de página.**

Meu código é praticamente isso:

```
node = document.getElementsByClassName("exemplo")[0];
if (node.parentNode) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

não sei se existe algum jeito ou função de fazer o site chamar esse código sempre que mudar seu estado mesmo não fazendo uma nova requisição.

Answer (score 0):

**Consegui achar a resposta!**

Basta utilizar esta função, passando tal parâmetro:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
   seuscodigos();
});
```

Pois a função **document.addEventListener();** Adiciona listeners no DOM do site e passando o parâmetro **'DOMNodeInserted'**, toda vez que algum nó for inserido na página, o código que você inserir dentro da função irá ser executado.

OBS: Não sei como marcar que a minha própria questão foi respondida.